# "Apple tax" in Japanese

Tags: words, translation

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Apple_tax) more or less defines "Apple tax" as

> The price premium paid by consumers of Apple consumer products over
>   comparable devices from competitors.

Is there an equivalent term in Japanese for "Apple tax" (or other mock taxes, such as a [wedding](http://www.yelp.com/list/weddings-are-hard-to-plan-so-im-eloping-san-francisco) [tax](http://offbeatbride.com/2007/11/wedding-tax) for increased costs of items when they're associated with a wedding)? If so, what is it?

I tried Wiktionary and jisho.org without any luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do say アップル[税]{ぜい} if that is what you are looking for.

For "wedding tax", I doubt that we have an exact counterpart but a somewhat-related, more generic word would be ご[祝儀価格]{しゅうぎかかく}, which literally means "celebratory price".